# Flex app not hitting web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, apache-flex, iis

I have zero knowledge on flex and need help to determine what is preventing my web service from being called.

We have a working application in production and the developer who wrote it has left.

I am trying to build it on my machine and I can see a web service call in fiddler being made with the URL "/Services.asmx/MethodName" (as a GET request).

I have set my break point in the asmx web service and it is not being hit. All I get in the flex front end is a pop up with " The remote server failed to respond and may be offline. http://MachineName/Services.asmx/MethodName"

The web service is in the same application as the web app that hosts the SWF file.

I have the cross domain policy file in place.

What I noticed in fiddler is the URL is "/Services.asmx/MethodName" and not "/WebApp/Services.asmx/MethodName" (not sure if this makes a difference) where WebApp is the IIS virtual directory to the web application that hosts the SWF.

Any ideas?

JD

Comment: Can you post some Flex Code?  How is the web service being called?  Is it using HTTPService, or RemoteObject, or WebService?  I don't know much about .NET debugging, but why would a Flex call trigger a .NET breakpoint?  Are you using one of the Visual Studio add-ins for Flex?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained more. I have the web app (asp.net application) that has a swf file. When I launch the app, one of the calls call a web service which I have a break point in. So it is simply a GET http request from the mxml file to the web service. There are no visual studio addins for Flex.

Comment: If it's just a "GET" request; then the SWF is probably using HTTPService, but that doesn't help explain why you're getting the error.

Comment: Thanks, without documentation this project is going to be a nightmare. I found somewhere in the code (and with the help of fiddler) that the a hardcoded path pointing to his machine was found. It seems to work now.

Comment: You should post that as an official answer to this question; as it did solve your problem.  If you need some help to dissect/document the code and/or provide you w/ some mentoring on Flex Development; there are many consultants (including me) who would be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Web-services and your web-application is same domain then just pass the whole path like "http://..../Services.asmx" for creating web-service api instance in ActionScript 3.0 (for flex). and use this instance name to call your web-service method.
[Please read this article from Adobe help for your perfect answer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html)